# Image cache present in which config file

Tags: media

I am new to drupal and was learning about image cache.So far its going good but I want to know where exactly the image cache config is getting saved.I mean to ask which file I have to browse to see image cache setting?If my doubt is silly then please forgive me.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Image cache is core in Drupal 7 IIRC. So you can access its config and settings via /admin/config/media/image-styles. The cached images themselves are saved in your theme/files dir as defined in /admin/config/media/file-system.

Comment: Thanks.As per my research even I have concluded the same.I was curious in which ".file" this image cache settings(code) are saved or getting append.Does my imagination works or not in drupal?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want exactly. The core functions reside in /modules/image/*. User-defined config presumably resides in db.image_styles and db.image_effects tables. You really don't want to be touching these files and tables directly however, which is the point of a UI.